# BugSense is crashing

Tags: java, android, exception, filenotfoundexception, bugsense

I am using BugSense, and it is working almost perfectly fine, including reporting bugs. The problem is that every time that the application is starting, it throws some exception (It looks like the application is going to crash (black screen) but it doesn't...)

Here's the stack trace:

```
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/.bugsense: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:66)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.UidUtils.getCurrentUid(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.UidUtils.getUid(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense.sendTick(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense.access$100(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense$4.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
07-28 11:21:48.373: I/BugSense(16173):  ... 14 more
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173): Cannot write file
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /mnt/sdcard/.bugsense: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:128)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:117)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.io.PrintWriter.<init>(PrintWriter.java:168)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.UidUtils.saveUid(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.UidUtils.getUid(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense.sendTick(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense.access$100(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense$4.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
07-28 11:21:49.718: I/BugSense(16173):  ... 15 more
07-28 11:21:49.773: D/BugSenseHandler(16173): Ready to send tick
07-28 11:21:50.078: D/BugSenseHandler(16173): Looking for exceptions in: /data/data/com.ronEven.blich/files
07-28 11:21:50.078: D/BugSenseHandler(16173): Found 0 stacktrace(s)
07-28 11:21:50.148: D/dalvikvm(16173): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 187K, 4% free 8849K/9159K, paused 40ms
07-28 11:21:50.148: I/dalvikvm-heap(16173): Grow heap (frag case) to 10.113MB for 1463056-byte allocation
07-28 11:21:50.178: D/dalvikvm(16173): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 4% free 10278K/10631K, paused 11ms
07-28 11:21:50.218: D/dalvikvm(16173): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 4% free 10277K/10631K, paused 1ms+2ms
07-28 11:21:50.343: D/CLIPBOARD(16173): Hide Clipboard dialog at Starting input: finished by someone else... !
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173): Transmitting analytics tick
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173): javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: No peer certificate
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.SSLSessionImpl.getPeerCertificates(SSLSessionImpl.java:137)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.AbstractVerifier.verify(AbstractVerifier.java:93)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:381)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:165)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense.sendTick(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense.access$100(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at com.bugsense.trace.BugSense$4.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
07-28 11:21:51.308: E/BugSenseHandler(16173):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

Thanks!

Comment: There is no file name starting with FULL-STOP(.), You are accessing that file which is not at said path.

Comment: But BugSense should be independent jar. It doesn't make sense that this is really the problem...

Comment: Where are you putting that jar file?? I mean in which folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-downloading and adding the jar did the job.
Maybe sometimes the most basic and stupid solution works the best...